# a form taking a long time to load and keep failing

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, form, performance

First, I would like to mention that, I am a database administrator, not a SharePoint Admin. we have a SharePoint 2010 site which provides a specific form. It was working fine until recently which start taking a long time to load the page and sometimes it even fails. The problem is not persistent, it starts running fine for few hours and the problem return back again.

I am monitoring it form the database side and it is not related to the number of users/high traffic. The jobs run fine even with a large number of users accessing it and sometimes the issue is there while even with only limited users connected.

I set up both performance monitoring and profiler trace and the result indicates that there is a higher number of blocking whenever this issue occurs. I went further and analyze the execution plan of each stored procedures involving on the blocking and found out that all those processes that are involved with the blocking also runs fine the on some occasions. From these results, I come to a conclusion that there must be some kind of Jobs running on the SharePoint side which cause this performance degradation and the blocking we are seeing is because of the stored procedure is waiting to get a requested resource (parameter) to be available.

However, the SharePoint admins keep telling me that there is no job running during this time. I have researched everything I could and but could not find the issues.

Can anyone of you guys give me a suggestion that I have to look after or monitor that can help me to identify the root cause of this problem? I highly appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: What the content of this form? Is there a custom web part or  It is the default SharePoint form? Do you face this issue for all forms?

Comment: Yes, this is the default SharePoint form. The issue is only on this site(all forms on this site). Forms for the other site runs just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Can you access SharePoint server?

If you can, go to the SharePoint server and check the ULS log in the SharePoint server when the issue occurs.

And you also could follow the troubleshooting steps in the article below.

Things to Check when an InfoPath Form Takes a Long Time to Load in Browser.

http://www.akspug.org/Blog/Post/99/Things-to-Check-when-an-InfoPath-Form-Takes-a-Long-Time-to-Load-in-Browser

And you also could follow the steps in the article to improve the performance of the form.

How to improve InfoPath Form Performance

https://support.winshuttle.com/s/article/Improve-InfoPath-Form-Performance